# Trouble executing all animation's using animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having some issues with my animations. The intended result is that the `UIButton`'s should both move to their positions, and once they reach their positions they must oscillate upwards and downwards, subtly, to simulate reaching the end of their bungee chord, if you will. The result I'm achieving is that every animation apart from the oscillation is executing perfectly. Why is this?  (The oscillation animation I refer to is, of course, the spring `animateWithDuration` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _orText.alpha = 0;

    //Email login button properties
    _emailLoginForwardButton.layer.cornerRadius = _emailLoginForwardButton.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.emailLoginForwardButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
    self.emailLoginForwardButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    [self.emailLoginForwardButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7)];
    _emailLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(77, 700, 40, 40);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^
     {
         _emailLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(77, 470, 40, 40);
     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                           delay:0.6
          usingSpringWithDamping:0.2
           initialSpringVelocity:0.4
                         options:0
                      animations:^(void){}
                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
          _orText.text = @"or";

          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                           animations:^
                           {
                               [_orText setAlpha:1];
                           }
          ];
      }
      ];
 }
 ];

//Google login button properties
_googleLoginForwardButton.layer.cornerRadius =_googleLoginForwardButton.frame.size.width / 2;
self.googleLoginForwardButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
self.googleLoginForwardButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
_googleLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(257, 700, 40, 40);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.4
                    options:0
                 animations:^
 {
     _googleLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(257, 470, 40, 40);
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                           delay:0.3
          usingSpringWithDamping:0.2
           initialSpringVelocity:0.4
                         options:0
                      animations:^
      {
      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished)
      {
      }
      ];
 }
 ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.googleLoginForwardButtonBottomConstraints.constant = -100.0;//e.g
    self.emailLoginForwardButtonBottomConstraints.constant = -100.0;//e.g

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                          delay:0.6
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.2
          initialSpringVelocity:0.4
                        options:0
                     animations:^(void){
                         self.googleLoginForwardButtonBottomConstraints.constant = 40.0;//e.g
                         self.emailLoginForwardButtonBottomConstraints.constant = 40.0;//e.g
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     }];
}
```

I have run this code and its working. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try it now. I just need to add constraints to my buttons, as nothing I've used so far has featured constraints. It'll be my first time working with them :D

Comment: If my answer helps you, please accept my answer. :)

Comment: So the spring animation works and the icon does move on screen, however the icon becomes huge (its a small, circular icon) and it also makes the other icon become huge. All I did was add a single bottom constraint to both buttons, and implemented the function only on the google button. Do you know why they're behaving like this? They also don't resposition in their places and hug the left of the screen at random places.

Comment: The behaviour is strange. I've added constraints to everything now, all this does is stretch the bottom of my UIButton and make it huge.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you are getting and what is expected?

Comment: I made a reply to this post, I posted my code. The problem with yours was, I think, you used the bottom constraint instead of the top constraint. I read that the top constraint controls the y-axis value, whilst the bottom simply works as the dimension of your actual object. So the behaviour I had was that the button did not move from outside of the bottom of the screen upwards to its position, but instead it stretched a lot and then wiggled.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0.6
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.42
      initialSpringVelocity:0.1
                    options:0
                 animations:^(void)
                 {
                     _orText.text = @"or";

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7
                                      animations:^
                      {
                          [_orText setAlpha:1];
                      }];

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      animations:^
                      {
                          _emailLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(77, 470, 40, 40);
                      }];

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                                      animations:^
                                      {
                                          _googleLoginForwardButton.frame = CGRectMake(257, 470, 40, 40);
                                      }
                     ];

                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

This was my solution, however there was more I wanted to do with this code. I wanted to make both buttons move at different intervals, and an if statement won't work here, for some reason. Also, I only wanted this to initialise when another action has taken place, which is still possible to do, but I'd prefer to be able to make them move at different times.